# Best approach for breaking dependencies in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

We are looking at adding unit tests to our C# code base. I am finding it easy to add unit tests to simple classes, but classes that interact with other dependencies are more difficult. I have been looking at mocking frameworks, but was wondering about the best approach to write classes in the first place to break external dependencies, like file system, database and messaging system dependencies.

To give an example, a routine listens on a socket for a message in a certain format - say MessageA. This is decoded, some calculations are done, this is re-encoded into a different binary format and the resulting message then sent, MessageB.

My current testing approach is as follows. I extract an interface for all socket interactions, and create a mock interface. I set the interface in a singleton. Then run the class against hard coded inputs. The class under test will use the interface in the singleton to send/receive.

I do a similar thing to test database interactions.

This does not seem like the most flexible approach, how would you go about improving this to make it easier to test? If a mocking framework is the answer, how would I design the classes?

Example code :

```
[SetUp]
public void init()
{
    // set message interface in singleton as mock interface
    CommAdapter.Instance.MessageAdapter = new MockMessage();

    // build reference message from hard coded test variables
    initialiseMessageA();

    // set input from mock message socket
    ((MockMessage) CommAdapter.Instance.MessageAdapter).MessageIn = m_messageA;
}

[Test]
public void test_listenMessage_validOutput()
{
    // initialise test class
    MessageSocket tS = new MessageSocket();

    // read from socket
    tS.listenMessage();

    // extract mock interface from singleton
    MockMessage mm = ((MockMessage) CommAdapter.Instance.MessageAdapter);

    // assert sent message is in correct / correstpoinding format
    Assert.AreEqual(1000001, mm.SentMessageB.TestField);

}
```

Comment: Drexiya, if you have some time, I strongly suggest you to read [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Signature/dp/0321503627). It's a 300 pages, easy to read book (you can finish it in a weekend). It's an excellent book that describes how to do unit test properly and talks a lot about how to use mocks. The code examples in the books are in Java, but I'm sure that you can take the abstract idea and apply it identically to C# using moq or a similar mocking library.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Augusto, I will definitely check that book out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using Singletons to set your component implementations, use a [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), and a [DI library like Ninject](http://ninject.org/).  This is exactly the type of scenario they were designed for.

Not pushing you to Ninject specifically, but they have a good tutorial :)  The concepts will transfer to other frameworks (like [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)).

- https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki

With DI alone, the code will look something like this:

```
class Samurai {
  private IWeapon _weapon;
  public Samurai(IWeapon weapon) {
    _weapon = weapon;
  }
  public void Attack(string target) {
    _weapon.Hit(target);
  }
}

class Shuriken : IWeapon {
  public void Hit(string target) {
    Console.WriteLine("Pierced {0}'s armor", target);
  }
}

class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    Samurai warrior1 = new Samurai(new Shuriken());
    Samurai warrior2 = new Samurai(new Sword());
    warrior1.Attack("the evildoers");
    warrior2.Attack("the evildoers");
  }
}
```

This looks clean now, but wait until your dependencies have dependencies, or further :)  You can use a DI library to solve that, though.

With a library to handle the wiring up for you, it will look something like:

```
class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    using(IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new WeaponsModule()))
    {
      var samurai = kernel.Get<Samurai>();
      warrior1.Attack("the evildoers");
    }
  }
}

// Todo: Duplicate class definitions from above...

public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule {
  public override void Load() {
    Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
    Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
  }
}
```

With either of these approaches, plus [a mock object framework like Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), your unit tests look something like this:

```
[Test]
public void HitShouldBeCalledByAttack()
{
    // Arrange all our data for testing
    const string target = "the evildoers";
    var mock = new Mock<IWeapon>();
    mock.Setup(w => w.Hit(target))
        .AtMostOnce();

    IWeapon mockWeapon = mock.Object;
    var warrior1 = new Samurai(mockWeapon);

    // Act on our code under test
    warrior1.Attack(target);

    // Assert Hit was called
    mock.Verify(w => w.Hit(target));
}
```

You'll notice you can just pass mock instances straight into the code under test, and you don't have to mess around with setting singletons.  This will help you avoid problems like needing to set up the state multiple times, or in between calls.  It means no hidden dependencies.

You'll also notice I didn't use the DI container in the tests.  If your code is well factored, it will only be testing a single class (and as often as possible, only a single method), and you will only need to mock out the direct dependencies of that class.

Comment: Hi Merlyn, thank you for the detailed response. I will look into this type of solution. Before I go too far down this route, do you think that this is overkill for applications that only need a limited amount of flexibility?

Comment: Also another concern is the overhead I would be adding to the code. I have seen some benchmarks that indicate Ninject can be a little slow.

Comment: One site claimed that StructureMap was a fast solution, but their introduction states : 'Do not use StructureMap if an application or process requires little flexibility. The abstraction and indirection afforded by StructureMap is unnecessary and even harmful in simpler systems or processes.'

Comment: @drexiya: You use the DI container once in the application root.  So you should only see slowdown on startup.  I haven't noticed it to be slow.  Anyhow there are a ton of DI libraries :)  As for "little flexibility", what do you mean your app needs little flexibility?  Being able to replace dependencies with mock objects sounds like flexibility-required to me...

Comment: @drexiya: If you really need very little flexibility, then you should be able to new-up your entire object graph in `Main`, and attach it all together.  Then you won't need a DI library, just the DI pattern.

Comment: @drexiya: Much like that first sample, except with `new TopLevel(new FirstDep(new SecondDep(), new SecondDep2()))`, etc.  Then you won't need a DI library, just the DI pattern.  That's also about as fast as DI can get.

Comment: Yes I see. Very helpful, thanks! I will test it out, and maybe do a bit of benchmarking to see if I am really getting much of a slow down.

Comment: @drexiya: If that chaining code works fine for you, definitely do it.  Don't import libraries if you don't need em :)  Make sure you chain it all in main, tho.  What you want to avoid is calling `new` anywhere inside any of your objects - you want to *inject* the dependencies.  Using abstract factories inside your classes is okay tho, as long as you injected the concrete factory.  You can also make dependencies "optional" by making them properties, and having a good default value that doesn't promote strong coupling, e.g. a "null logger" for a logger dependency.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a DI container (I'm using MS Unity 2.0 currently but there are many to choose from) you will need a good mocking framework, my preference is MOQ.  A common pattern/process for breaking concrete dependencies is:

- define the dependency via an interface; you may luck out and already have an interface, like IDbConnection or you may need to use Proxy to wrap a concrete type and define your own interface.
- resolve the concrete implementation via your DI container
- inject your mock implementations into your DI container at test setup time (inject real impls. at system startup)

Comment: apologies @Merlyn Morgan-Graham, this is pretty much the same answer

Comment: No need to apologize.  While SO doesn't specifically condone duplicate answers, it doesn't really discourage them either.  The assumption is that they will be inevitable - people often are reading the question at the same time.  Voting solves that problem.  +1 on this answer since it is still good, and compact.  I recommend you skip using a DI *container* in unit tests tho.  I don't think it is necessary.